# Add new indices to particular level of a MultiIndex dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
data = io.StringIO('''Fruit,Color,Count,Price
Apple,Red,3,$1.29
Apple,Green,9,$0.99
Pear,Red,25,$2.59
Pear,Green,26,$2.79
Lime,Green,99,$0.39
''')
df_unindexed = pd.read_csv(data)
df = df_unindexed.set_index(['Fruit', 'Color'])
```

Output:

```
Out[5]: 
             Count  Price
Fruit Color              
Apple Red        3  $1.29
      Green      9  $0.99
Pear  Red       25  $2.59
      Green     26  $2.79
Lime  Green     99  $0.39
```

Now lets say I want to count the number of keys in the 'Color' level:

```
L = []
for i in pd.unique(df.index.get_level_values(0)):
    L.append(range(df.xs(i).shape[0]))

list(np.concatenate(L))
```

Then I add the resulting list `[0,1,0,1,0]` as a new column:

```
df['Bob'] = list(np.concatenate(L))
```

as so:

```
             Count  Price  Bob
Fruit Color                   
Apple Red        3  $1.29    0
      Green      9  $0.99    1
Pear  Red       25  $2.59    0
      Green     26  $2.79    1
Lime  Green     99  $0.39    0
```

**My question:**

How do I make the `Bob` column an index *on the same level as `Color`*? This is what I want:

```
                 Count  Price
Fruit Color Bob                   
Apple Red    0    3     $1.29
      Green  1    9     $0.99
Pear  Red    0   25     $2.59
      Green  1   26     $2.79
Lime  Green  0   99     $0.39
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for `cumcount`? If so, you can ditch the loop and vectorize your solution.

```
df = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
print(df)
               Count  Price
Fruit Color                
Apple Red   0      3  $1.29
      Green 1      9  $0.99
Pear  Red   0     25  $2.59
      Green 1     26  $2.79
Lime  Green 0     99  $0.39
```

Or, if you'd prefer doing this in one fell swoop,

```
df_unindexed = pd.read_csv(data)
df = df_unindexed.set_index(['Fruit', 'Color', df.groupby('Fruit').cumcount()])
print(df)
               Count  Price
Fruit Color                
Apple Green 0      9  $0.99
      Red   1      3  $1.29
Lime  Green 0     99  $0.39
Pear  Green 1     26  $2.79
      Red   0     25  $2.59
```

To rename the index, use `rename_axis`:

```
df = df.rename_axis(['Fruit', 'Color', 'Bob'])
print(df)
                 Count  Price
Fruit Color Bob              
Apple Red   0        3  $1.29
      Green 1        9  $0.99
Pear  Red   0       25  $2.59
      Green 1       26  $2.79
Lime  Green 0       99  $0.39
```

Comment: But how do you access the cumcount index now? Or how do you give it a name like 'Bob'?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, Use the `append` argument of `set_index`:

```
df.set_index('Bob',append=True,inplace=True)
>>> df
                 Count  Price
Fruit Color Bob              
Apple Red   0        3  $1.29
      Green 1        9  $0.99
Pear  Red   0       25  $2.59
      Green 1       26  $2.79
Lime  Green 0       99  $0.39
```